# avada woocommerce product details in grid

Tags: css

Using avada theme and woocommerce when the products are listed on page load, picture is over product text on first load. After reload it all aligns. Please refer to the picture below.

Any suggestions why. there are no error on load in console. Also I cleaned all cache, updated all plugins  etc.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use CSS to make more space between the image and the title, with a margin to the image and also `overflow: hidden` to the image.